# Should I level the subfloor before or after adding another layer of subfloor?

Tags: flooring

When laying a second layer of plywood subfloor to support granite tiles, does the original plywood subfloor need to be leveled first or just level the floor after adding the second layer? I have about a 1/4” dip.

Also, if the new layer is 3/8” plywood, is it necessary to remove the toilet flange, or is an extender sufficient?

Answer (score 2):

I level and true the floor then add layers. Leveling compounds fracture easily and if covered with a layer of plywood or backer board this will provide the best base. With divots or voids under plywood there will be flex and cause problems with the tiles and grout.

Comment: What does the phrase "true a floor" mean?

Comment: Removing divots level is one thing but with venal this is more important than level I know this is tile but I want a good base for any floor level and true.

Comment: So you mean making the surface flat/smooth?

Comment: @tylerh Yes, in some cases level is irrelevant (floor drains) but any divots will show through vinyl and for someone that is a novice to tile I have seen high edges because the tile was set on a divot it had a high edge /corner on the other side. With respect to true with a floor drain the slope and any changes will match the tile size or again you end up with high edges to me that shows rookie diy.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are after subfloor strength I think you'd want to level after you put the other layer down.  I assume you are gluing and screwing the 2nd layer to the first.

TCNA typically wants 1-1/4" thick subfloor.

Comment: It is a 5’ x 8’ bathroom.  It has 3/4” plywood subfloor on joists at 16 inches. So adding 3/8” will only make it 1&1/8” thick. I thought that 1” was the minimum thickness to support the weight of granite. 

The dip of 1/4” spans the 5’ width of the room and the dip is about 2 feet across.